# Change content of a selection box w.r.t. another

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am new in web development. I have 2 selection (Box1 & Box2 - drop down). I want Box2 contents to be changed according to the first box's selection. How can i do this ?

```
Box1:<br>
<select name="country" class="field-select">
<option value="selected">Options</option>
<option value="Color">Color</option>
<option value="Food">Food</option>
</select>

Box2:<br>
<select name="item" class="field-select">
<option value="Red">Red</option>
<option value="Orange">Orange</option>
<option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
<option value="Apple">Apple</option>
<option value="Banana">Banana</option>
<option value="Watermelon">Watermelon</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What is the source for `Box2` ?

Comment: If value "Color" is selected in Box1, Box 2 will show option "Red", "Orange" & "Yellow only". But if  value "Food" is selected, Box2 will show options for "Apple", "Banana" & "Watermelon" only.

Answer (score 0):

There are few methods from which this can be achived:
1. Using Database
2. Using JSON

I may be showing you how to execute this using JSON

Create a JSON file (data.json) and place in the same foleder in which the HTML file is placed

**JSON [data.json]**

```
{
    "color":"Red,Orange,Yellow",
    "food":"Apple,Banana,Watermelon"
}
```

**HTML & jQuery [fiddle.html]**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Fiddle</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<select id="first-choice">
    <option selected value="base">Options</option>
    <option value="color">Color</option>
    <option value="food">Food</option>
</select>
<br>
<select id="second-choice">
    <option>Please choose from the above</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log($("#first-choice"));
        $("#first-choice").on("change", function(){
            var $dropdown = $(this);
            $.getJSON("data.json",function(data){
                var key = $dropdown.val();
                var vals = [];

                switch(key){
                    case 'color':
                    vals = data.color.split(",");
                    break;
                    case 'food':
                    vals = data.food.split(",");
                    break;
                    case 'base':
                    vals = ['Please choose from above'];
                }
                var $secondChoice = $("#second-choice");
                $secondChoice.empty();
                $.each(vals,function(index,value){
                    $secondChoice.append("<option>" + value + "</option>");
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **jQuery** to populate *Box2* based on the selected value of *Box1*. The solution would be like this:

- Add an `id` attribute to each of your `<select>` Box, and don't pre-populate *Box2*, like this:

  ```
  Box1:<br>
  <select name="country" class="field-select" id="box1">
      <option value="selected">Options</option>
      <option value="Color">Color</option>
      <option value="Food">Food</option>
  </select>

  Box2:<br>
  <select name="item" class="field-select" id="box2">
      <option>--</option>
  </select>
  ```

  **Note:** If you want you can change this line `<option>--</option>` in *Box2* and add your own custom `<option>`, it won't cause any harm to the overall logic.
- And your jQuery would be like this:

  ```
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $(document).on('change', '#box1', function(){
              if($(this).val() == 'Color'){
                  $('#box2').html("<option value='Red'>Red</option>"      
                      +"<option value='Orange'>Orange</option>"
                      +"<option value='Yellow'>Yellow</option>");
              }else if($(this).val() == 'Food'){
                  $('#box2').html("<option value='Apple'>Apple</option>"
                      +"<option value='Banana'>Banana</option>"
                      +"<option value='Watermelon'>Watermelon</option>");
              }
          });
      });
  </script>
  ```

---

Here's the live demo, https://jsfiddle.net/dmrmwfm4/